# PHP PDO Max Value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So let's say I have a column called groupID, it is a number given to a group of people. Basically all I want to do is get the largest value from that column, add 1 and store that input into a variable in php.

For example, if the last group's id was 5, then the next group's id should be 6. Any ideas?

```
$gid = $link->prepare("SELECT MAX(Group_ID) FROM Conference");
$gid->execute();
$groupid = $gid->fetchColumn();

$stmt = $link -> prepare("INSERT INTO Conference (`Group_ID`) VALUES (:groupid)");
$stmt->bindParam(':groupid', $groupid);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: ok i got what you want... can you tell us what have you done so far...

Comment: @Surace yes, i posted the code now.

Comment: Would be better not to repeat the same question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It would be much simpler to use an [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html) column, when you wouldn't have to concern yourself with this at all.

To solve it manually, `SELECT MAX(id) FROM table` will give you the largest id currently in use, and adding +1 to that would achieve the goal. This is susceptible to race conditions (what if two clients do this and get the same value from `MAX()`?), but the recovery mode is very simple: repeat until successful.

Comment: @Richard: I 'd just write `$gid->fetchColumn();` but yes that looks right.

Comment: Okay i added the other piece of code where I actually insert. Does that all look right now? For some reason my page won't load properly. Earlier it's done this when there's some code problem. And the console isn't showing anything either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

$gid = $link->prepare("SELECT MAX(Group_ID) FROM Conference");

$stmt = $link -> prepare("INSERT INTO Conference(`Group_ID`) SELECT MAX(Group_ID) FROM Conference");

$stmt->execute();

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
$gid = $link->prepare("SELECT MAX(Group_ID) as maximum FROM Conference");
```